Why is Spring looking for a local SMTP server
I have been attempting to implement password resetting into my application, and to do so I want to send the user an email with their verification code.  I have built the java mail implementation like this
Config:
@Configuration class MailConfig {
    @Bean fun javaMailSender(): JavaMailSender = JavaMailSenderImpl()
}

Service:
@Service class MailService {
    @Autowired lateinit var sender: JavaMailSender

    fun sendMail(email: String, text: String) {
        val msg = sender.createMimeMessage()
        val helper = MimeMessageHelper(msg, true)
        helper.setTo(email)
        helper.setSubject("Test")
        helper.setText(text)
        sender.send(msg)
    }
}

application.properties:
spring.mail.host=smtp-relay.brevo.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=(senderId)@smtp-brevo.com
spring.mail.password=(password)
spring.mail.properties.mail.smptp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.starttls.required=true

I simply call the sendMail() method from my REST endpoint that handles sending reset requests, but the server generates the following error when the endpoint is hit:
jakarta.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP host: localhost, port: 25, response: 421 Cannot connect to SMTP server
However, I do not understand why it is looking for the server on 127.0.0.1:25, when the properties specify a completely different host and port.  I have double checked the property names as well as the login information for my smtp service. I believe the issue is somewhere in application.properties, as I confirmed the code I wrote to implement the mail service with the following: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email

You don't use a custom bean with spring boot. It is instanciated and configured in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderPropertiesConfiguration.
If you provide the bean for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.JavaMailSenderImpl yourself, you also have to take care to configure it.
